# When I store same index by string in dictionary it show error

Tags: c#, dictionary

My question is how to compiler check index in string.if index is integer I know compiler Check not number repeat but index is string How to check index is duplicate or not.

```
Dictionary<string, int> cityCode = new Dictionary<string,                  
cityCode.Add("JPJ",12580); 
cityCode.Add("JPJ",50780);
```

Index is same "jpg" And compiler show error its true, but i am question is how to check compiler index is same by string key not integer key

Comment: Question is unclear. Please clarify your question and fix formatting

Comment: Index is same "jpg" And compiler show error its true, but i am question is how to check compiler index is same by string key not integer key

Answer (score 2):

> if index is integer I know compiler Check

No that is not true, compiler doesn't check for duplicate even if the index or `Key` for dictionary is integer.

> How to check index is duplicate or not.

Use [`Dictionary.ContainsKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like:

```
if(!cityCode.ContainsKey("JPJ"))
{
     //Add if not present. 
}
```